# Filter contents of a QTableView connected to SQLite database via QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qsqldatabase

How can I filter the contents of a QTableView that is connected to a SQLite database via QSqlTableModel?

For example, if the database contains a "name" column, I want to show only the rows where the name is "Jack"?

Comment: If you want to show database content, the right way is to use `QTableView` with a model.  Then you can search on the model using `QAbstractItemModel::match` or `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [QSqlTableModel::setFilter()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter). The filtering will be done by the model, and the view will automatically update itself to show only the filtered items.

> The filter is a SQL WHERE clause without the keyword WHERE (for example, name='Josephine').
>
> If the model is already populated with data from a database, the model re-selects it with the new filter. Otherwise, the filter will be applied the next time select() is called.